# Wrong shaped face

Tags: mesh, faces

I am trying to create a face using 3 vertices from this

[image]

But the face formed is not a pointy triangle but rather, an odd shape like this
[image]

Comment: I tried deleting the edges and re-creating the edges then form a face but the face still isn't a pointy triangle.

Comment: You probably have some duplicated vertices. Select all and use W then 'remove doubles' (this is noticeable because on top image, we do not see orange/yellow lines going along the edges from the selected vertices)

Comment: @lemon Oh my goodness, you are a life-saver! Thank you so much, it has solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @lemon, problem occurred due to duplicated vertices.

Select all -> W -> Remove doubles solved the problem.
[image]